# Get all processes which have a name that contains the same word in Java

Tags: java

For a Java program, I want to get all processes which have a name that contains the same word (for example "cheese") and to kill them.

I searched on stackoverflow but all possibilities I have tried do not work.

I know how to kill a task but not how to get all processes which have a name that contains the same word.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post some of your code attempts. Otherwise you are going to get a bunch of down votes and comments saying the SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Step 1: get the list of all running processes. Step 2: use a regex to find the ones matching your word. Step 3: kill the processes that match. Step 4: cry as you made a mistake in your regex and killed all processes on your machine ...  (I'm just saying it's probably a bad idea in the first place)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is the problem? What operating system are you using? Having bad English is not a problem but providing insufficient information about your problem is.

Comment: “I search on stackoverflow but all possibilities I have tried do not work”  Edit your question and explain some of the things you tried, with the code you used, and explain the results you got for each of them.  Until you do, your question is just asking someone else to do all of the work for you, rather than solving a specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: This only works on windows computers.

This will create a list with all the process that have `word` in their name.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getProccessWithString(String word){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.indexOf(word) > 0){
                list.add(line);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
    }
```

And it is called like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = getProccessWithString("word");
```

Then you can use a loop to kill them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM " + list.get(i));
}
```

You will need to run this program as administrator because `taskkill` is an elevated command.

Comment: The last code appears to be OS-specific. Not all code runs on Windows.

Comment: @AndyThomas I know, it is difficult to work outside of your own OS though :/

Comment: But the task is not kill :/

Comment: @D.Dreko What is the output? I can change the code to kill it

Comment: You might not be able to directly copy/paste this in all situations but this code is still useful.